# Check if range of values is ascending, descending, or non-monotonous

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

I am looking for a hint to find out strictly the condition for non monotonous.

The string of numbers ends with the value 0, where 0 is not part of the heights (only marks the end of the string).

Specify whether the range of heights is ascending, descending, or non-monotonous.

```
Input             Output
---------------------------
1 2 5 5 10 11 0   ascending
16 7 3 0          descending
1 2 2 1 0         non-monotonous
```

---

Solving as much as possible with while and if and int.

Restrictions and clarifications:

- 0 is not part of the string of heights, only marks the end of the string
- heights are numbers between 0 and 10,000
- for simplicity if all numbers are equal or there is no value before 0, the string is considered non-monotonous

How I tried to solve it :

```
int main(){

    int   b ,  a   , ascending = 0  , counter = 0 , descending = 0 ;
    
       cin >> a;
     while( a != 0 ){
        cin >> b;
         ++counter;
    if( a && b != 0 ){

        if( a <  b ){
         ++ascending;
        }
        else if(a > b ){
         ++descending;
        }
        }
           a = b;
    }
     --counter;
     if(ascending == counter  ){
         cout << "\n ascending";
     }
     else if ( descending > 2 ){
         cout << " non-monotonous ";
     }

     if(descending == counter){
         cout << "\n descending ";
     }
     else if ( ascending > 2 ){
        cout << " non-monotonous ";
     }
}
```

Comment: *"I would not want all the code for this problem."* -- then don't post the whole problem. Isolate the one point from the problem that concerns your question, and ask about that. (By the way, good goal.) *Example: your question centers around "Specify whether the range of heights is ascending, descending, or non-monotonous.", right?*

Comment: The answer is none. Your requirements state as much. If it’s not ascending and it’s not descending, it’s non-monotonous. You don’t need to check if it is non-monotonous when it’s the only option left.

Comment: If there are no entries, the sequence is non-monotonous. After the counts, if all the numbers are ascending and all the numbers are descending, then they're all equal, and the sequence is non-monotonous; otherwise, if all the numbers are ascending, the sequence is ascending; otherwise, if all the numbers are descending, the sequence is descending; otherwise, the sequence is non-monotonous.

Comment: If I don't have "no entries"  is it the same thing with 0 practically?                                  
                                                                                                             
Thanks a lot for the comment

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to make two bool variables and name it `ascending` and `descending` and assign true to them. And also always keep the `current` number that you have and the `last` number.

Then you can execute the while loop how you do it

If you get this situation:

`last_number>current_number`

then you just assign false for ascending variable

and if you have `last_number<current_number`

then conversely

After you loop is over, the answer will be in this variables.

Comment: You also have to detect all variables equal.

Comment: @PeteBecker you right)

Answer (score 1):

here is how i would solve it but don't worry, i will explain how I reasoned when I wrote the code.
this solution is to be considered useful for school purposes only since using c++ standards utilities you can check the sequence with a near two lines long check (other users have responded with much more fast, clean and sane methods than this)

```
int main()
{
    bool descending = true;
    bool ascending = true;
    bool equals = true;
    
    int num = -1;
    int last_num = -1;
    
    std::cin >> num;
    last_num = num;
    
    while( num != 0 ){
        if(ascending)
            ascending = last_num <= num;
        if(descending)
            descending = last_num >= num;
        if(equals)
            equals = last_num == num;
        
        last_num = num;
        std::cin >> num;
    }
    
    if(equals)
        std::cout << "non-monotonous";
    else if(descending)
        std::cout << "descending";
    else if(ascending)
        std::cout << "ascending";
    else
        std::cout << "non-monotonous";
    return 0;
}
```

In this case you can't store the whole sequence and exam it at the end.
So the unique way you got to check what condition (ascending, descending, non-monotonous) is respected is to store what conditions are still valid with the previous integers and to check them with the new one.

To do this i stored (is)`descending` (is)`ascending` and (is)`equals` in three (initially true) booleans.
Every time i get a new input i check what of them is still true, once verified what conditions are still true i can check them one by one (only the ones that are still true) and verify if the new input break one of them.

When the while is finished (and i got the last 0 number which is discarded) the last phase is to check which conditions are still true, giving priority to (is)`equals` since it can be true without invalidate the other two conditions.

`descending` and `ascending` are self-excluding so only one of them can be true, so no matter what of these two i check after the first (`equals`).

In case i got three false condition the sequence is surely non-monotonous.

---

EDIT (Thanks to [@Pete Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593860/pete-becker) for the hints)

We can improve the code making it shorter and cleaner with two more things.

-The first point is the conditions check about `descending` and `ascending`.
For brevity we could make it like this :

```
    ascending &= last_num <= num;
    descending &= last_num >= num;
```

The bitwise operator `&=` apply the AND operation on the bits of `ascending` and `descending` variables. The unique way for these variables to keep `true` as value is to pass to &= operator only true right values. In short, if only once the right value is false, the bool value of the variable will be false for the rest of the loop.

-The second point is about `equals` variable.
It is not strictly necessary since we can know if all values are equal by checking if both `descending` and `ascending` are true.

Comment: If you're into brevity, the tests in the loop can be written `ascending &= lastnum <= num;` etc.

Comment: Re: "only one of them can be true" -- both will be true if all the inputs are equal. You're right that the code avoids the problem by checking `equals` first. On the other hand, `equals` isn't strictly necessary; if `ascending` and `descending` are both true, then all the elements were equal. +1.

Comment: i m going to post your hints

Answer (score 0):

If you have a range of integers*, you can use `std::is_sorted` to write the following function

```
std::string monotonous(std::vector<int> const & v)
{
    if (v.empty() or 
        std::equal(std::begin(v), std::end(v) - 1, std::begin(v) + 1))
       return "non-monotonous";
    if (std::ranges::is_sorted(v))
        return "ascending";
    else 
    if (std::ranges::is_sorted(v, std::greater{}))
        return "descending";
    else
       return "non-monotonous";
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jf7E9Pz1r).

If you don't have C++20, the `std::ranges::is_sorted` can be replaced with `std::is_sorted`, and the iterators into the range have to be specified explicitly, e.g. `std::is_sorted(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::greater{})`.

---

*if the values are being read in from standard input, add them to a `vector<int>` (except for the last `0`), and then call the function.

Comment: what in case all numbers are equal?
the user require `if all numbers are equal or there is no value before 0, the string is considered non-monotonous`

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper Good point, thanks. Edited to check for equal values, as well as empty ranges.

Comment: If I had this case : 1 0  what should it show me ? Maybe ascending ?                        I do not know how this case can be considered..

Comment: @Large_Emu3782 I'm not sure I follow. Deciding what output you get from a particular input is up to you. According to your problem description, the 0 at the end would be ignored, and the range containing 1 should return non-monotonous, since it's a range containing all equal elements.